# Merge two tables and UPDATE one attribute WHERE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables looking like this:

Games(Name, Maker, Year);

Fees(Name, ID, Price, Players);

I want to update the price of the games that has the maker 'Microsoft'.

Any help is appreciated.

I think the way is to merge the two tables where the names are equal and then update the Fees.price where Maker = Microsoft. But I'm unsure on how to do it.

I believe the answers from both @SheldonNeilson and @Gordon Linoff works, although I could only grant one checkmark.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: How are the two tables related? By `Name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to reduce the price by 10% for all Microsoft games, then you can use:

```
update fees
    set price = price * 0.9
    where name in (select g.name from games g where g.maker = 'Microsoft');
```

Note that this is standard syntax should work in any database.

Comment: What does the g in g.name and g.maker stand for?

Comment: It is a shortcut for the `games` table. Notice `select g.name from games **g**`

Comment: @bronislav So games.name and games.maker would be the right syntax?

Comment: @Colour No. Notice the `g` in `from games g`. It is syntax to define shortcut. It could be anything but `g` looks good. After using alias, it's accessible only using new name.

Comment: I see @bronislav, I simply forgot to comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE fees
   SET fees.Price = fees.Price * 1.1
  FROM Fees fees
  JOIN Games games
    ON games.Name = fees.Name
 WHERE games.Maker = 'Microsoft'
```

Comment: Will this do the same as the first answer? Except for the * 1.1 ofc.

Comment: What is the use of an alias that is identical to the table name?

Comment: Yes.. but nested select statements are generally slow so this would perform better. You really need to look into using proper primary & foreign keys though.

Comment: @SheldonNeilson Thank you. I sure will do that!

Comment: @SheldonNeilson I don't think that such minor changes worse separate answer. Preferred is to comment / edit existed ones.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: so you don't have to type out the entire table name all the time.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the alias is not identical. I use a lower case equivalent because an alias is a requirement of this type of statement and using the full name assists with readability when your queries get to 100s of lines long. Just habit.

Comment: SQL is not case sensitive therefor `Fees` and `fees` are identical identifiers (and now that we know which DBMS is being used the answer isn't correct - it probably only was correct for SQL Server)

Comment: @Colour: do not use this answer for Postgres. Repeating the target table of an update in the `from` clause is wrong in Postgres and results in an cross join of the table to itself - definitely not something you want.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Would it be correct in MySQL then? And should I use the answer from Gordon instead?

Comment: Indeed.. i answered this with MSSQL in mind before you specified.